# Cron like Apps Script Trigger function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a function that I run in Apps Scripts via a trigger every 15 minutes.   This is apparently too much as it runs on the weekends when is unnecessary.   Id like to be able to run this script every fifteen minutes Monday - Friday only.  I know you can do this through a cron job but I am trying to determine if I can accomplish this via Apps Scripts Triggers.

The Documentation is not cleared on this or maybe I am missing something.

Does anyone know if this is something that can be done via Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: Yes by just checking for the appropriate days within your script. Date().getDay() Sun-Sat 0 - 6 don't run the function on 0 or 6  or run the function from 1-5 your choice

Comment: @Cooper Im no t sure I am following.  is this something that is custom written inside of your script as suppose to an actual Trigger?

Comment: It's javascript.  You really need to javascript if you want learn google apps script

Comment: @Cooper I understand that, however, I am not sure where to place it.   Does that go inside the same function?

Comment: @Cooper ok?? 
I never asked for the script to be written, I can write it on my own.  I have plenty of Appscripts written but couldnt get a straight answer from the docs.   Your answer did help me so I thank you for that but the assumption was uncalled for.

Comment: What am I suppose to assume you asked a question you didn't show any research and you didn't have a [mcve].

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunc() {
  let dt=new Date().getDay();
  if(dt>0 && dt<6) {
  //do stuff here
  }
}
```

[Date().getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger (really triggers) like that programmatically.

Example:

```js
function createTriggers() {

var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
if(triggers.length == 0){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
      
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY)
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
      
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
      
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
      
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
      }}
```

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder).

Comment: @Cooper I think it's less wasteful because it only runs it on M-F. If someone uses an if clause with .getDay() then it is also being called on Sat and Sun just not actually running the full script. Great idea about checking if triggers exist. I just added that. If the OP is using other triggers it would have to be a more complicated if statement but that should work if those are the only ones.

Comment: I was actually just thinking about how this question seems irrelevant. The trigger quota is per day, is it not? I think 90min/day or 6hrs/day depending on account.

Comment: Oopps commented at same time. Hmm I guess I don't understand. How is it using the trigger quota more? It should use it less although hardly any since the runtime of yours is basically zero. I suppose your answer should be just as good although isn't technically what the poster asked for.

Comment: That's why I said this: "If the OP is using other triggers it would have to be a more complicated if statement but that should work if those are the only ones." With this documentation they should be able to figure it out: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this using code. You can create a trigger from the Apps Script user interface that executes a particular function of your Javascript code. You need to press Add Trigger button and there you will be able to:

- choose which function to run
- which deployment
- event source (select time-driven)
- type of time based trigger (minutes timer)
- select minute interval (Every 15 minutes)

I had a similar situation and in my case I created an automation that runs every Monday executing a Javascript function that loads data into a google spreadsheet.

hope this can help :)